# MVC6 - upload a CSV file and string to controller using Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am having trouble with this.  I need to send a CSV file along with the value of a string variable back to the controller.

I have already managed to send the file via the submit button of the form (just through submit) and I have also managed to send the string variable back to the controller (using ajax post) but when I combine these together and its not working.

I have search for downloading/uploading files (all files types) on this forum but at this point not found what I wanted. The closest I have come to is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132229/how-to-send-javascript-file-object-data-to-mvc-6-controller-asp-net-5).

This is CSHTML form:

```
<form asp-action="FileIndexView"
      asp-controller="SuburbsAndPostcodesAdmin"
      method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Select the Suburbs and Postcodes latest CSV File:</label>
            <input type="file"
                   name="CSVFile"
                   id="txtFileUpload"
                   class="col-md-8 control-label" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit"
                   name="Submit"
                   value="Submit"
                   class="col-md-1 btn btn-primary"
                   disabled="disabled"
                   id="SubmitFile" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
//On button click send the connection id back to method FileIndexView.
$('#SubmitFile').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button

    var fileUpload = document.getElementById("txtFileUpload");
    var url = "/SuburbsAndPostcodesAdmin/FileIndexView";
    var connId = $.connection.hub.id;

    //$.post(url, {"fileUpload": file, "connId": connId });

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { file: file, "connId": connId },
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Yay! It worked!');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Oh no :(');
        }
    });

});
```

and here is the controller IActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult FileIndexView(IFormFile file, string connId)
{
 ...stuff
}
```

Its MVC6 so I am using IFormFile.

I did try and place the contents of the id for the file into a variable but it just gets lost... You will notice I also tried using $.post as well. I can get back to the controller if I only send the string variable.

Whats wrong with the way I have tried to send the file and how should it be presented so that the controller with an IFormFile argument and string argument accept the Ajax post?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a FormData object to post your file+string?

```
var fd = new FormData();    
fd.append( 'file', connId);
fd.append( 'connId', input.files[0] );

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert('Yay! It worked!');
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Oh no :(');
        }
});
```

Comment: How would the [HttPost] IActionResult look like. Do I fashion a viewmodel to manage the return?

Comment: There’s one thing to consider though: browser support for FormData starts at IE 10. But a fallback solution should be easy to provide as we can just sent the form using a regular HTTP request.